# Application hangs at detectMultiscale

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am developing a face detection algorithm in c++ visual studio with haar cascade method.

At the below line application quits while the same application works perfectly in linux environment.

Is there any opencv configuration which might cause this?

Any help would be really great.

```
frontfaceCascade.detectMultiScale(grey_image, faces, 1.1, 0, 0 |
                                  CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));
```

Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <corecrt_math_defines.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
vector<Mat> Frames;
void getFrames(char* fileName);
cv::CascadeClassifier frontfaceCascade;
cv::CascadeClassifier sidefaceCascade;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << " enter file name: \n";
        exit(1);
    }

    char* fileName = argv[1];

    //  if( !frontfaceCascade.load("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml")){
    if (!frontfaceCascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")) {
        std::cout << "Error Loading frontface haarcascade" << std::endl;
    }


    if (!sidefaceCascade.load("haarcascade_profileface.xml"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error Loading sideface haarcascade" << std::endl;
    }

    namedWindow("Faces", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow("Faces", 100, 400);
    moveWindow("Faces", 30, 100);
    getFrames(fileName);
    return 0;
}

void getFrames(char* fileName) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap(fileName);
    if (!vcap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat grey_image;
    Mat img;
    namedWindow("Frames", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    resizeWindow("Frames", 640, 360);
    moveWindow("Frames", 130, 100);
    int init = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        vcap >> img;
        // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        if (img.empty())
            break;

        unsigned int prevSize = 0;
        resize(img, img, cv::Size(640, 360));
        cv::cvtColor(img, grey_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        //cv::equalizeHist(grey_image, grey_image);

        std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

        frontfaceCascade.detectMultiScale(grey_image, faces, 1.1, 0, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30)); // Minimum size of obj
        //sidefaceCascade.detectMultiScale(grey_image, faces, 1.1, 4, 0 | 1, Size(40, 40), Size(100, 100)); // Minimum size of obj

        /****/
    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    vcap.release();
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole code or at least the most important blocks (specially where you define `frontfaceCascade`, `grey_image` and `faces`).

Comment: _Hangs_ or _quits_?

Comment: It hangs and then quits.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: @OscarMartinez Thanks,  have added the code in the question.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes I have done it now. I am getting "Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr. " error. In this line. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried every compiling posibilities? Try to run it in Debug/Release mode and x64/x86 architectures

Comment: @OscarMartinez Thanks, it works well in Debug x86 mode.

Comment: Glad to know it :)